# Yii extension that generates metrics

Tags: php, yii, metrics

Is there any extension to Yii which generates metrics for the project? I have been trying to use PHP_Depend with no luck, always fails with an error message saying

`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to PHP_Depend_Code_ASTNode::setParent() must implement interface PHP_Depend_Code_ASTNodeI...`

Anybody knows of an extension to Yii?

Comment: By metrics, do you mean code coverage?

Comment: Yeah, I mean metrics such as afferent & efferent coupling, number of method or function calls, number of lines of comment code, lines of code, number of classes.. etc

Comment: Just installed php_depend via Pear and ran it against my current trackstar application and it went through without a problem. At first guess you have an actual php fatal error in your project somewhere. might want to turn on php logging and check your php_error.log file

Comment: I had installed php_depend via Pear as well, and my solution was to end up running it against a smaller group of folders leaving some files outside that seemed to be causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it will cover all the metrics you want but phpunit with code coverage extension can output reports including crap rating. Yii is already plugged into phpunit so all you need to do is run the tests...

Comment: Yes, I read about that. But, according to [this](http://es.scribd.com/doc/78113553/41/Generating-code-coverage-reports) reference, **"the code coverage report is generated based only on tests you have run. It is better to run the complete test pack for the project  to get the actual information, but for simplicity and speed, only a few tests of the Yii framework code were executed."** I haven't run any tests, so (correct me if I am wrong), but this wouldn´t generate the code coverage metrics, right?

Comment: Correct, you'd need to create the phpunit tests for your projects and run them...which I presume you're doing anyway as good practice :)

Comment: Well, that's what I *should* have done... but no, it isn´t! Time pressured, I was a beginner with Yii, so I skipped that important step. So unfortunately this code coverage extension isn't useful in my case. It is the only extension available?

Comment: Not aware of any other yii extensions for code coverage. You might want to try a different Pear extension though, like PHP Mess Detector: http://phpmd.org/

Comment: I marked your answer as correct, thanks for the help. In the end I used PHP_Depend (as I said on the other comment, running it against a smaller group of folders), but this would have been the right way to go if I had been doing things right and had created phpunit tests for my project. Thanks again!